# How would you describe the different nature of DOM abstraction between jquery and angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller, abstraction

I am looking for a description of what I believe being a totally different approach to DOM abstraction between jquery and angular, but I can't find it.

I think I know both jquery and angularjs relatively well after years developing using the former and then the latter.

DOM abstraction done with jquery looks fundamentally different than DOM abstraction done with angularjs.

But I can't find a formal definition of those differences, and I don't know if it's a change in the design pattern of client side web apps and if so what's the philosophy behind it.

Theoretically jquery decoupling of logic from DOM it's more strict, because all the js code is left out of the HTML, but in reality (in my opinion) angular directives (combined with two-way binding) allow you a much more clean and concise DOM abstraction.

But is that a shift in web development patterns? Looks so, both knockout, react, ember, and probably more... Share that similar approach.

Is it just a consequence of going MVC?

If anyone could point me to some theory behind that I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try thinking of it in terms of "imperative" vs "declarative". With jQuery you write JS that creates a strict DOM structure, tied to the data you are trying to display (you loop over an array and for each item generate a `<tr>` for example). With AngularJS you introduce a new "language" - a layer of abstraction - between the data (models) and the representation (DOM) that we sometimes call "bindings". The way an `ng-repeat` works under the hood is not that different than writing a jQuery loop that generates `<tr>`s, but you don't directly do that yourself, it's abstracted under a nice declarative wrapper where you tell AngularJS that you'd like to have a list of stuff in the DOM and that list should be bound to a list of stuff in your model layer.

Let me make this clearer: internally AngularJS uses a "tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows Angular to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way" - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element